# How to remove the extra space between the mdframed environments?

Tags: mdframed, amsthm

In contrast with the `amsthm` environments, the gap between `mdframed` environments are larger than that of `amsthm`.

[image: Extra space between the mdframed envrionments]

The MWE is the following

```tex
\PassOptionsToPackage{svgnames}{xcolor}
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor,amsthm,mdframed}

\makeatletter
\theoremstyle{definition}
\def\th@definition{%
  \thm@notefont{}% same as heading font
  \normalfont % body font
}
\newmdtheoremenv[
    hidealllines=true,      linecolor=MidnightBlue,
    leftline=true,          linewidth=.5ex,
    innerleftmargin=1.5ex,  innerrightmargin=0pt,
    innertopmargin=-1.7ex,  innerbottommargin=0]
{definition}
{\color{MidnightBlue}Definition}[chapter]

\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}

\begin{document}

A test with singlespacing:

\begin{definition}[The Definition Environment]\leavevmode\newline
    From WikipediA: A definition is used to give a precise meaning to a new term, by describing a condition which unambiguously qualifies what a mathematical term is and is not.
\end{definition}

\begin{definition}[The Definition Environment]\leavevmode\newline
    From WikipediA: A definition is used to give a precise meaning to a new term, by describing a condition which unambiguously qualifies what a mathematical term is and is not.
\end{definition}

\begin{lemma}[The Lemma Environment]
    
\end{lemma}

\begin{lemma}[The Lemma Environment]
    
\end{lemma}

A test with onehalfspacing:
\linespread{1.5}

\begin{definition}[The Definition Environment]\leavevmode\newline
    From WikipediA: A definition is used to give a precise meaning to a new term, by describing a condition which unambiguously qualifies what a mathematical term is and is not.
\end{definition}

\begin{definition}[The Definition Environment]\leavevmode\newline
    From WikipediA: A definition is used to give a precise meaning to a new term, by describing a condition which unambiguously qualifies what a mathematical term is and is not.
\end{definition}

\begin{lemma}[The Lemma Environment]
    
\end{lemma}

\begin{lemma}[The Lemma Environment]
    
\end{lemma}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Length options of [mdframed](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mdframed) boxes are described in section 6.3 of its documentation. Try `skipabove` and `skipbelow`:

```tex
\newmdtheoremenv[
    skipabove=0pt,          skipbelow=0pt,
    hidealllines=true,      linecolor=MidnightBlue,
    leftline=true,          linewidth=.5ex,
    innerleftmargin=1.5ex,  innerrightmargin=0pt,
    innertopmargin=-1.7ex,  innerbottommargin=0]
{definition}
```

[image]